# I can't get rid of an infinite poison effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So I was playing on one of my mod packs (1.12.2 if this helps), and had been bitten by a vampire and had turned, everything was normal until then. As in, when I turned I got an infinite poison effect, and I cannot get rid of it, at all. Milk buckets don't work neither does the `/effect @p clear` command. Even the `/kill` command does nothing, it just comes back. I have no clue how to get rid of it since this has never happened before and there is nothing about it anywhere I can find.  I mean you can see how an infinite poison effect can be annoying when you are trying to play in survival.

Here's the list of mods if you need it

- Astikor Carts
- Baby Animals
- Backpack
- Baubles Mod
- Bewitchment Mod
- Biomes O Plenty
- Code Chicken Lib
- CoFH Core
- Craftable Saddles
- Fossils Archeology
- Just Enough Items
- LLibrary
- OptiFine
- Patchouli Mod
- Redstone Flux API
- Tree Chopper
- U Team Core
- Vampirism

Comment: It sounds like that's just part of being a vampire. I would guess that it's intended.

Answer (score 1):

Try dying naturally (without /kill) or getting out of sunlight (as you were bitten by a vampire).

As a last resort, if no other solution works, you'll have to delete your player data from the save. Be sure to put your items in a chest before doing this so that they're not lost forever.

1. Close your world if it is open
2. Open [NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer)
3. Navigate to your world folder
4. Delete the entry named as your UUID in playerdata.
5. Delete the default player entry in level.dat (level.dat/player)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are wearing any faction specific items that aren't for vampires, the effect won't go away until you take them off.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not wearing any obsidian armor from hell, it's poisonous to vampires.